# Variable declaration not allowed in Java

Tags: java, constructor

This is a java poker project from my school project.

At the beginning, Card class is defined.

```
class Card {

/* constant suits and ranks */
static final String[] Suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
static final String[] Rank = {"","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

/* Data field of a card: rank and suit */
private int cardRank;  /* values: 1-13 (see Rank[] above) */
private int cardSuit;  /* values: 0-3  (see Suit[] above) */

/* Constructor to create a card */
/* throw MyPlayingCardException if rank or suit is invalid */
public Card(int rank, int suit) throws MyPlayingCardException { 
if ((rank < 1) || (rank > 13))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid rank:"+rank);
else
        cardRank = rank;
if ((suit < 0) || (suit > 3))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid suit:"+suit);
else
        cardSuit = suit;
}

/* Accessor and toString */
/* You may impelemnt equals(), but it will not be used */
public int getRank() { return cardRank; }
public int getSuit() { return cardSuit; }
public String toString() { return Rank[cardRank] + " " + Suit[cardSuit]; }
```

Then, I tried to define the Deck class. But I had some error.

```
class Decks {

/* this is used to keep track of original n*52 cards */
private List<Card> originalDecks;   

/* this starts with n*52 cards deck from original deck   */
/* it is used to keep track of remaining cards to deal */
/* see reset(): it resets dealDecks to a full deck      */
private List<Card> dealDecks;

/* number of decks in this object */
private int numberDecks;

  public Decks()
{
    ArrayList<Card> originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
    ArrayList<Card> dealDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52); 

     Card card = new Card(j,i);   //Error

    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)  
        for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++)              

              originalDecks.add(card);   //Error

    dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks); 


}
```

public Decks(int n)
    {

```
    int numberDecks=n ; 

    Decks originalDecks = new Decks();

    for (int m=0; m< n; m++){

         originalDecks += originalDecks ; 

    }


}
```

The idea is that: first, I tried to create one deck with 52 cards; then I tied to loop it n times to create n decks. However, I got some unresolved error showing me that

> Cannot find symbol i, j.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you try to create a `Card` before you define `i` and `j`. Also, please use braces.

```
// Card card = new Card(j,i);
for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {  
    for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++) {
        Card card = new Card(j,i);
        originalDecks.add(card); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to move it in, but it shows me new error: "variable declaration is not allowed here".

Comment: @LijieZhou Did you add the braces?

Answer (score 2):

for this statement

```
Card card = new Card(j,i);
```

there is no variable `i` or `j` in the scope and so it is legit compilation error

you want to move them inside inner loop

```
 for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)  {
        for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++) {              
            Card card = new Card(j,i);
            originalDecks.add(card); 

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly RuntimeError  "variable declaration is not allowed here" is because of lack of Braces.

Example:-

```
public class Creator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        Creature creature=new Creature(); // Error 

        System.out.println(Creature.numCreated());

    }
}
```

On compiling this code is giving error: variable declaration is not allowed here.

But,

```
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {Creature creature=new Creature();} //no error
```

This will resolve the error.